# Can web app and database be hosted on different servers (remote and local)?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, server, hosting

I apologize right away if I misuse my right to ask questions here. Yet, being a tyro in web development and an ASP.NET beginner, I need some advice from the experts.

I have developed an ASP.NET WebForms application which I would like to deploy to a remote hosting server. The application constantly queries and updates the database due to its purpose of being a document registration system. It will be sold to different institutions so that I've imagined the following scenario: host the app on the same server for all the institutions and have the databases  on a different server or on multiple different servers. I have considered this option because as the data amount expands the storage provided by hosting companies may be insufficient.

My question is: is it possible to accomplish this scenario and if yes what are the risks and how should I do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a normal way to do it. However, you need a fast network connection between the web server and database server. You would also need to consider the service level (ie percentage up-time) and how much redundancy is needed to achieve that.

There's an easy way and a harder way to achieve this.

The easy way is to host your application in Microsoft Azure. It is fast to implement and very flexible.

You can host the database in SQL Azure Database, which Microsoft recommend for new development. This can be scaled from very small (and low cost) to very powerful (more cost).

Similarly the web application can be scaled. You can scale it vertically, by making the machine more powerful, and horizontally by adding more machines.

For both the database and web application, the scaling can be changed up or down in a few minutes.

The harder way is to host the application on virtual machines. You would need a lot of knowledge to configure and maintain this. For instance, you might need to configure SQL Server AlwaysOn.

This screen picture shows how you can select the pricing tier for a web application hosted in Microsoft Azure. (Prices are in GBP.)

[image]

You should host the web app and the database in the same data centre to ensure there will be fast network connections between them. Also you can make them belong to the same "resource group", which tells Azure that they work together.

This shows how you can select the level for a SQL Azure database. (Prices in GBP.)

[image]

See Microsoft Azure > Azure pricing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/

Comment: I see... what about hosting the database locally? Are there serious security issues apart from the fast Internet connection needed?

Comment: Don't even think about it! As you say, fast Internet connection, reliability, firewall issues. How will you provide redundancy in case the database server goes down? How will you scale it? What about peak loads?

Comment: Do you have the staff to maintain the database server locally? What happens if it goes down at 3 am? Do you have sufficient systems administrators to cope with holidays?

Comment: In your question, you are concerned that the amount of storage provided by the hosting company might not be sufficient. Microsoft Azure can provide virtually unlimited storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the explanations!

Comment: You're welcome. Really, Microsoft Azure is so nice to work with and it doesn't have to be expensive. Azure can be complex, but configuring a website to work with a database is straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it, just consider the speed between the hosting server and database server.